# generating value rows in between dates

Tags: sql, hive

I have a data table that lists id changes on a given date. Structure is the following (**Table A**):

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| person current_id previous_id action          date       |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| A      1          0           'id assignment' 2019-01-01 |
| B      2          1           'id change'     2019-01-03 |
| A      2          1           'id change'     2019-01-02 |
| C      4          2           'id change'     2019-01-03 |
| ...    ...        ...         ...             ...        |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

However **Table A** provides a date **only** if there was a change on that date.

For a traceability study, I am trying to create a data table (**Table B** below) using **Table A**. Each day **should** contain the corresponding id for the existing people in that table (using hive).

Something like this (**Table B**):

```
+---------------------------+
| date          person  id  |
+---------------------------+
| 2019-01-01    A       1   |
| 2019-01-01    B       1   |
| 2019-01-01    C       2   |
| 2019-01-02    A       2   |
| 2019-01-02    B       1   |
| 2019-01-02    C       2   |
| 2019-01-03    A       2   |
| 2019-01-03    B       2   |
| 2019-01-03    C       4   |
| ...           ...     ... |
+---------------------------+
```

All I can do is getting time independent current ids for mentioned people. I have no idea where to start on generating  the output table. Cannot establish the logic.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to generate the rows.  Assuming that you have at least one change on each day, you can use a `cross join`.

Then you need to impute the value on each days.  The simplest method would use `lag()` with the ignore nulls option, but I don't think Hive supports this.

Instead, two levels of window functions can work:

```
select person, date,
       coalesce(current_id,
                max(current_id) over (partition by person, id_date)
               ) as id
from (select p.person, d.date, a.current_id,
             max(case when a.current_id is not null then d.date end) over (partition by p.person order by d.date) as id_date
      from (select distinct person from tablea a) p cross join
           (select distinct date from tablea a) d left join
           tablea a
           on p.person = a.person and d.date = a.date
     ) pd;
```

If you cannot use `cross join`, perhaps this will work:

```
      from (select distinct person, 1 as joinkey from tablea a) p join
           (select distinct date, 1 as joinkey from tablea a) d
           on p.joinkey = d.joinkey left join
           tablea a
           on p.person = a.person and d.date = a.date
```

Comment: I might be a bit lost to follow the query. What does alias a refer to? Cannot find the initial assignment to a table? If refers to **Table A** can you update so that it is referred as tablea or something similar?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't work in our hive environment as we are obliged to use strict mode enabled and cross join is not allowed. Is there a workaround where we can replicate the cross join to avoid strict mode limitation?

Comment: OK, making progress here. Hive complains p.date part is missing in your query. Is it the last part should be "on p.person = a.person and d.date = a.date"  instead?

Comment: Unfortunately this query generates null records instead of the actual id for any given day except when a change occurs (correct id) and the day before that (with a wrong id)

Comment: Found the issue with help of a colleague from work!!! Apparently its the case statement that generates id_date. It should be: "max(case when a.current_id is not null then d.date end) over (partition by p.person order by d.date) as id_date"    If you edit it, I will accept it as correct answer!